# Group on excel rows to a single cell by column id

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a question regarding excel.

I have two columns, column A has a number and B has country codes. I'm looking for a way to automatically go through 100's thousands of rows to group them so they look like the following...

Is this doable? I'm at a complete loss :(

THE END RESULT

```
6512    AG,AI,AW,BB,BL,BM,
6513    BQ,BS,BZ,CA,CR
```

STARTING POINT - column A & B

```
6512    AG
6512    AI
6512    AW
6512    BB
6512    BL
6512    BM
6513    BQ
6513    BS
6513    BZ
6513    CA
6513    CR
```

Comment: are the records (column A) in sorted order?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? You're more likely to get help if you have.

Comment: I did SJR from using lookups to VB but can't seem to get it to work. I should have posted my examples here.

Answer (score 0):

These solutions use a working column named *Concatenated Results*.

Assuming your data has a header *(adjust formulas as required)* and is located at `B6:C34` *(change as required)* as in fig below.

**Data sorted by `ID`**:

*Concatenated Results:* Enter this formula in `D7`.

```
= CONCATENATE( C7, IF( EXACT( B7, B8 ), "," & D8, "" ) )
```

*ID.Unique:* Enter this `Array Formula` in `E7` (*FormulaArrays are entered pressing* <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly*)

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( $B$7:$B$34,
MATCH( 0, COUNTIF( $E6:$E$6, $B$7:$B$34 ), 0 ) * 1 ), "" )
```

*Countries:* Enter this formula in `F7`

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E7,$B$6:$J$34,3,0),"")
```

Copy range `D7:F7` till last row of data *(i.e. row 34)*.

**Data not sorted**: If the data is not sorted enter this formula for the *Concatenated Results* in `D7`. *All other formulas remain unchanged*.

```
=CONCATENATE( C7,
IF( ISERROR( MATCH( B7, B8:B$35, 0 ) ), "",
"," & VLOOKUP( B7, B8:D$35, 3, 0 ) ) )
```

[image]

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[Excel functions (alphabetical)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188), [Create an array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-E43E12E0-AFC6-4A12-BC7F-48361075954D), [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7)

Answer (score 0):

This is a VBA solution

Assuming your data, excluding header, is located at `B7:C34` (change as required).

*ID.Unique:* Enter this Array Formula in E7 (*FormulaArrays are entered pressing* <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly*)

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( $B$7:$B$34,
MATCH( 0, COUNTIF( $E6:$E$6, $B$7:$B$34 ), 0 ) * 1 ), "" )
```

*Countries:* Enter this `User Defined Function` *(UDF)* in F7

```
=Match_Concatenated(E7,$B$7:$C$34)
```

Copy this UDF code in a VBA Module

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Match_Concatenated(vValue As Variant, rTrg As Range) As String
Dim sOutput As String
Dim vTrg As Variant, vItm As Variant, lRow As Long
    vTrg = rTrg.Value2
    For lRow = 1 To UBound(vTrg)
        vItm = WorksheetFunction.Index(vTrg, lRow, 0)
        If vItm(1) = vValue Then sOutput = sOutput & Chr(44) & vItm(2)
    Next
    sOutput = Replace(sOutput, Chr(44), vbNullString, 1, 1)
    Match_Concatenated = sOutput
End Function
```

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[Excel functions (alphabetical)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188),

[Create an array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-E43E12E0-AFC6-4A12-BC7F-48361075954D),

[Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7),

[Option Explicit Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278855(v=office.15).aspx),

[Range.Value2 Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553(v=office.15).aspx), [For...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251601.aspx),

[WorksheetFunction Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx), [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd),

[If...Then...Else Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251599.aspx),  [Replace Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264409(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and let me know in case of any queries or if you require detailed explanation.

**Step1:** `Filter` the data by column A.
**Step2:** Make a new column C where use this formula `IF(A2=A1,CONCATENATE(B2,",",C1),B2)`  .
**Step3:** Make a new column D where use this formula `IF(A2=A3," ","REQUIRED_ANS")` .
**Step4:** Filter on column D using `ALT` + `D` + `F` + `F` and you get you desired output.

**My Output:**
[image]